# Download file via button and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an action that returns (downloads) an excel file in the following manner:

```
 public IActionResult CreateExcelFile(string id, int xx, string start, string end) {

//Some additional code...
// ....
// ....
        var file = File(doc, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        file.FileDownloadName = filename + " " + id + ".xlsx";
        return file;
}
```

So far, I have triggered this action from a view like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">Some Content</div>
```

And lastly the JavaScript:

```
$(function excelFunction() {

  $('#myDiv').click(function () {

    alert("Initiate excel export")
    var start = $('#startDateTextBox').val();
    var end = $('#endDateTextBox').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Customer/CreateExcelFile',
        data: { id: 'FVM10000', xx: '4', start: start, end: end },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.type == "success") {
                alert("success")
            }
            else {
                // Do something else
                alert("failure")
            }
        }
    });
  });
});
```

I enter the debugging mode and see that the action is indeed called with the correct parameters, however, after the action is executed, no file is returned (or downloaded). I get an alert message saying "failure", which indicates that the response was not completed.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't need to use AJAX call for a file request. Just open a new window to '/Customer/CreateExcelFile' sending the needed params. The browser will download the file or ask for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle file download from ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use ajax for file downloads. Do the normal HTTP request to your action method.

```
$('#myDiv').click(function () {

    var start = $('#startDateTextBox').val();
    var end = $('#endDateTextBox').val();
    var url='/Customer/CreateExcelFile?id=FVM10000&xx=4&start='+start+'&end='+end;
    window.location.href=url;
});
```

I would also recommend using the html helper method to generate the correct relative path to the base portion of your action method. you can execute the `Url.Action` helper method and store the result of this call in an html 5 data attribute in your div.

```
<div id="myDiv" data-url="@Url.Action("CreateExcelFile","Customer")">Some Content</div>
```

Now in the script read this value and do the querystring concatenation.

```
$('#myDiv').click(function () {

    alert("Initiate excel export")
    var start = $('#startDateTextBox').val();
    var end = $('#endDateTextBox').val();
    var url=$(this).data("url")+"?id=FVM10000&xx=4&start="+start+"&end="+end;
    window.location.href=url;
});
```

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you. How would I introduce a parameter to this javascript? Within the view I have a model property that I want to pass along to the JS.

Comment: If that parameter exist in your CreateExcelFile action method, you can add that to the method call.(Ex :`@Url.Action("CreateExcelFile","Customer",new { name=Model.FirstName})`. Now since the url already has a `?`, you should do `&` as the first one to start instead of `?` when you concatenate querystring params in your js code

Comment: You´re absolutely right. It works! Thank you so much!! @Shyju